# PHP return numeric name from json

Tags: php, json, foreach

I have code:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=0');
$coins = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($coins as $coin) {
  echo $coin->24h_volume_usd;
}
```

Script return me error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '24' (T_LNUMBER), expecting
>   identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'...

Yes, I know I can't used name JSON with number, but I can't change `24h_volume_usd` to for example: `h_volume_usd`, because this is value download from other page ([ink](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/)).

Comment: Change the object to an array? Perhaps that will work? You can do that with `json_decode()`, but that part is missing from your code.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Not work, when I change to: `echo $coin['24h_volume_usd'];` I have error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: You need to change the object to an array, of course. For instance like Aniket Sahrawat says.

Comment: it's version PHP 7.2. I added code to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an object key starts with digits, you need to wrap it as string literal in braces, like this:

```
$coin->{"24h_volume_usd"};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can decode the json-string into an associative array, by setting the second parameter to true.

```
$coins = json_decode($jsonString, true);
foreach($coins as $coin) {
  echo $coin['24h_volume_usd'];
}
```